# Linear Programming Standard Form matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, linear-programming

In a linear program in standard form the contraints are expressed as

$$A \bar{x}=\bar{b}$$

where A is a $m \times n$ matrix with $n > m$. Why is it that $n > m$ is required?

Comment: If $m > n$, the linear system $\rm A x = b$ is *overdetermined* and may very well have no solution. In that case, the LP is infeasible. It is natural to see *underdetermined* linear systems in LP.

Answer (score 1):

The usual purpose for putting an LP into standard form is to solve it via the simplex algorithm (or some variant thereof). That means you insert slack/surplus variables to convert inequality constraints to equations. If all the original constraints were inequalities, you are guaranteed that $n$ (which includes the $m$ slack variables) is greater than $m$.

If, say, you start with all equation constraints, it is in fact possible that $m > n$ at the outset. To invoke the simplex algorithm, you use what is known as the two-phase method, in which you insert "artificial" variables and, in phase 1, minimize their sum. So, again, after you've added the $m$ artificial variables, your new $n$ is greater than $m$.

For a mix of equations and inequalities, you insert artificials in the former, slacks in the latter and, yet again, have more columns than rows.

It's perfectly possible to have an LP with more constraints than variables; but to use the simplex method, you have to transform as above.